# Prop inheritance from component

Tags: vue.js

Not too sure if i understand "Non-prop attributes" from manual (or vue.js at all): https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Say i have ChildComponent.vue file:

```
<template>
  <input type="text" class="input" :value="childValue" v-on="listeners">
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      childValue: {
        type: String,
        default: 'blah',
      }
    },
    computed: {
      listeners() {
        return {
          // Pass all component listeners directly to input
          ...this.$listeners,
          // Override input listener to work with v-model
          input: event => this.$emit('input', event.target.value)
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Then I add it to ParentComponent like this:

```
<template>
  <ChildComponent v-model="parentValue" placeholder="default" @keydown.enter="parentMethod"/>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        parentValue: "",
      };
    },
    methods: {
      parentMethod () {
        ...
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

The flow should be (and works like this) - anything written to text field in ChildComponent after pressing enter should be sent all the way up to ParentComponent as `parentValue` and `parentMethod()` should be invoked.

1. If I understand correctly BasicComponent is kind of extension to its template's root component, meaning `<input>` will not only have props type and class set, but also `placeholder` (which has "default" value)?
2. Also, does this mean that the `v-model` prop to whom `parentValue` data is assigned will be propagated to `<input>` element as well, making my `:value` and `v-on` bind reduntant?
3. Another question - how the hell is `v-on="listeners"` working without specifying an event, does it mean i'm listening to EVERY event?
   In the parent component there is a shorthand `@keydown.enter` which means it's listening for keydown.enter event, yet in `listeners()` method I'm emitting an `input` event...
4. I also have big trouble understanding what is going on in `listeners()` method at all, so any help in deciphering this will be greatly appreciated. :D

Thanks in advance for help.

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's do this one topic at a time...

### **Difference between props and non-prop attributes:**

Props are the parameters which you define in your `props` object. With props you can tell the user what types they should use for a given prop, whether they're required or not, default values, assign validation functions, and etc.

Also, props are reactive, so if your template depends on a prop and the prop updates, so will your template.

Attributes you assign to your components, but do not correspond to any props, are passed to the `$attrs` variable. You can use it to access those values, like `$attrs.id` to get the id, or `$attrs.name` to get the name, and so on.

### **The event flow in your case:**

Yes, the things you type on your `ChildComponent` *are* passed to `ParentComponent`. They are passed both via your `v-model` and via `@keydown.enter="parentMethod"`.

You probably know how events work, but if you don't, here's the gist of it: When you need to pass data from a child component to a parent component, you emit an event in your child and listen to it in your parent.

For example, if you want to emit an event called foo, you would call `$emit` somewhere in your child, using `$emit('foo')`. Then, you'd listen to it in the parent by adding `@foo="yourHandler"` to the child, where `yourHandler` is a function written to handle the event. Which is what you did with `@keydown.enter="parentMethod"`.

### **`<input>` will not only have props type and class set, but also placeholder (which has "default" value)?**:

Answer: It depends. What the `<input>` tag in your template will receive depends on whether or not your root element (`<input>`) inherits component attributes. That behavior is defined by the `inheritsAttrs` property of a component, which defaults to true.

What that means is, in your case, since you haven't specified `inheritsAttrs` it will default to true, and **yes**, every attribute you pass to `<ChildComponent>` will be passed to your `<input>` tag, except for the things you defined manually.

Since you declared your `<input>` tag like this:

```
<input type="text" class="input" :value="childValue" v-on="listeners">
```

Your `<input>` tag will inherit all attributes from `<ChildComponent>` **except** `type`, `value` and your listeners (more on that later). The exceptions to that rule are `class` and `style`, which are always inherited regardless.

**PS:** Note that `type`, `class` and `placeholder` are attributes, not props.

### **Does this mean that the v-model prop to whom parentValue data is assigned will be propagated to  element as well, making my :value and v-on bind reduntant?**

Answer: No, but it also won't work. Here's why:

When you declare your listeners using this piece of code:

```
listeners() {
    return {
        // Pass all component listeners directly to input
        ...this.$listeners,
        // Override input listener to work with v-model
        input: event => this.$emit('input', event.target.value)
    }
}
```

You are assigning to your `listeners` computed property every single event listener placed on your `ChildComponent` tag, including your `keydown` event, which is why it works.

The assignment is done in this line:

```
...this.$listeners,
```

It uses the spread operator to add all the elements in your `$listeners` variable (which holds all your component events) to the object you're returning.

The only event which you are not inheriting is `input`, as defined in this line:

```
input: event => this.$emit('input', event.target.value)
```

With that line, you tell your code that the behavior of your `input` event will be the one you defined, rather than the inherited.

Then, when you assign `v-on="listeners"` to your input, you're telling it to listen to every single event listed on your `listeners` variable. That is: You're appending all your inherited events and your custom `input` event to your input event.

Finally, to explain why it isn't redundant but why it won't work, you must understand how `v-model` works. It (usually) works by listening on the `input` event of a component, and using it to update the `value` prop of the same component. So in this line:

```
<ChildComponent v-model="parentValue" placeholder="default" @keydown.enter="parentMethod"/>
```

You are doing two things:

- You're assigning the value of `parentValue` to the `value` prop of `ChildComponent`
- You're telling your component to update `parentValue` whenever the `input` event is called.

That means that assigning a value and listeners to your `input` tag is not redundant, since you need it for `v-model` to work properly, but it won't work in the end, since your component doesn't have a `value` prop. it has a `childValue` prop instead.

To fix it, you have two options:

- Rename `childValue` to `value`
- Or tell your component to use `childValue` as model

To do the second approach, just append this piece of code to your `ChildComponent`:

```
model: {
    prop: 'childValue',
    event: 'input'
}
```

That will tell your component to use that prop and that event to make `v-model` work.

## **THE END**

**A final note:** In the future, try narrowing your question down to a single topic. It will be easier to answer and will help people who search for those topics later on.

Comment: Thank you so much. 
Just one more clarification, I've read that:
"v-model internally uses different properties and emits different events for different input elements". 
So for textarea elements the prop will be 'value', however for things like checkboxes this is gonna be 'checked' property. 
I tested both your solutions and they do work, however in first approach how does it know that 'value' should be prop to be used in v-model?

Comment: Does BasicComponent somehow inherit type from its <input> root component, or is 'value' prop the default one and things like checkboxes override 
it using the model : {} method u showed me in 2nd approach? Or maybe there's other magic I'm not aware of.

Comment: `value` is the default for any **custom** component (that is, components written by the user). Different input fields have their own defaults, like `checked` for checkboxes.